# Setting ylim in pyplot does not work, but xlim does

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a series of plots that have to have the same axis scale for comparison in a gif. When I go to set limits on the colorbar and x axis, the limits work. But they do not for the y axis.

I am working with matplotlib 1.4.3, and Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Here is the plotting routine (this is part of a while loop that goes through my data):

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(MSTAR, radii, c=MU_MEAN_MODEL, cmap='YlGnBu', vmin=17, vmax=22.5, alpha=0.6, marker='.')
plt.errorbar(median_masses, median_radii, xerr=m_mass_errs,
             yerr=median_radius_errs, color='firebrick', alpha=1, fmt='.')
bar = plt.colorbar()
bar.set_label("MU_MEAN_MODEL")
plt.xlabel("M*")
plt.yscale('log')                                                                                                                                              
plt.axis([10.6, 12.4, 0, 11])
plt.ylabel("Physical radius (kpc)")
plt.title("Redshift " + str(zbin) + ", SPMOD cut not applied")
plt.savefig("filename" + str(i) + ".png")
```

I have tried replacing `plt.axis([10.6, 12.4, 0, 11])` with

```
axes = plt.gca()                                                                                                                                                   
axes.set_xlim([10.6, 12.4])                                                                                                                                        
axes.set_ylim([0, 11])
```

and

```
plt.ylim([0, 11])                                                                                                                                                   
plt.xlim([10.6, 12.4])
```

Neither has shown results. See an animation of the plots I am getting below.

[image: Animation of plot sequence, illustrating y axis rescaling]

Comment: Figured out my own silly mistake. I was giving matplotlib a lower limit of zero on the y axis, which on a log scale is not defined. So, it appears, matplotlib simply ignored the ylim command.